# Postgres database connections: password authentication failed in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Rubymine refuses my authentication like in the
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRf1x.png).

I changed the password in the [.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhM5K.png) but it
doesn't work.
I only know that there is a simple solution. 
But which one?

Comment: Does this error occur only when you are trying to connect via Rubymine, or when you launch your application too?

Comment: but when I set localhost in the web, lauching is broken:

Comment: `2017-08-09 22:18:12 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!' `

Answer (score 0):

When I launch via the terminal, it seems ok:

```
/home/knut/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production => Booting Puma => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in production on 0.0.0.0:3000 => Run rails server -h for more startup options Puma starting in single mode... * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5 * Environment: production * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 Use Ctrl-C to stop ` ` but the result via the web localhost doesn't work `2017-08-09 22:18:12 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-08-09 22:18:13 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-08-09 22:18:13 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-08-09 22:21:06 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-08-09 22:21:09 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/knut/projets/RoR_Postrgre/vendor/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```